# Is it possible to artificially trigger ReadDirectoryChangesW?

Tags: c++, windows, shell, winapi, metadata

I'm creating an application for changing file metadata.  I'd prefer that metadata edits not affect a file's modified date, so I'd like to suppress modification-date changes by doing this:

```
FILETIME ft = { 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF };
SetFileTime(hFile, NULL, NULL, &ft);
```

The only downside is that this apparently results in `ReadDirectoryChangesW` not being triggered, so changes don't sync over something like Dropbox.  I was wondering if there's a way to suppress the modification-date changes but also to artificially trigger `ReadDirectoryChangesW` so that modifications register.  In other words, to have the best of both worlds.  Is that possible?  Thank you very much for any info.

Comment: You are modifying a file. Why don't you want the modifications to update the file's last-modified timestamp? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you're right.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by file metadata, but if you're writing to an ADS I highly doubt Dropbox syncs these anyway.

Comment: @rem: Would you really expect your last modification timestamps to update whenever your antimalware solution finished scanning a file?

Comment: @IInspectable scanning a file does not modify the file, unless an infection is removed. The OP specifically stated that the target file is being modified.

Comment: @rem: Have you precluded the possibility of the scan result getting put into an ADS?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot artificially trigger `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`, especially if you are not the listener.  `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` is monitoring the filesystem itself, so only real filesystem events will trigger it.

Comment: Sounds good, but I had one last idea (although I can't seem to get it to work).  What if, instead of using `FILETIME ft = { 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF };`, you just obtained and stored the current modification date, then updated the file, and then applied the stored modification date?  Couldn't that theoretically work?

Comment: @loop123123 you could, but that would introduce a race condition. Updating the file would trigger events, but who is to say that listeners don't act on the events before you have a chance to reset the timestamp?